# How do I remove extra space in python?

Tags: python, whitespace

This is some of my python code:

```
my_fancy_variable = input('Choose a color to paint the wall:\n') 

if my_fancy_variable == 'red':
    print(('Cost of purchasing red paint:\n$'),math.ceil(paint_needed) * 35)
elif my_fancy_variable == 'blue':
    print(('Cost of purchasing blue paint:\n$'),math.ceil(paint_needed) * 25)
elif my_fancy_variable == 'green':
    print(('Cost of purchasing green paint:\n$'),math.ceil(paint_needed) * 23)
```

I am just trying to get rid of the space between the "$" and "105.

There's more code but basically I'll get a result of:
`Cost of purchasing red paint: $ 105`

Thanks!

Comment: @CaptainTrunky That question pertains to Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print function has a default argument, `sep`, which is the separator between each argument given to the print function.

By default, it is set to a space. You can easily change it, (to nothing in your case) like so:

```
print('Cost of paint: $', math.ceil(paint_needed), sep='')
# Cost of paint: $150
```

If you wanted to separate each argument with a newline character, you could do this:

```
print('Cost of paint: $', math.ceil(paint_needed), sep='\n')
# Cost of paint: $
# 150
```

`sep` can be any string value you need (or want) it to be.

Comment: I believe the question wanted the dollar sign with the amount and newline after the whole line

Comment: I'm responding to the second example

Answer (score 0):

I would use format strings for legibility:

```
f"Cost of purchasing blue paint: ${math.ceil(paint_needed) * 25}"
```

Another point here is how many ifs are you going to add? Indigo / orange etc.

```
colours = {
   'red': "$35",
   'blue': "$25",
   'green': "$23"
}

cost = colours.get(my_fancy_variable, "Unknown cost")

print(f"Cost of purchasing {my_fancy_variable} is {cost}")
```